# magento 2 sort by name is not showing full products

Tags: magento2, product, php, catalog, product-sorting

Magento 2.4 on the category page when sort by selected is name then products are not showing all products

sort by position is working fine

sort by price is working fine

Example Total 31 products in X category, when we select sort by is name on first page it is showing 6 products(half of 12 products)
and when we go on 2nd page it is show 6 products(half of 12) and same on 3rd page it is showing 6 products which is correct.

Anyone aware about this error or how we can resolve this ?

Comment: Are you using any extension or module for Product permissions?

Comment: @ArunSharma not using any extension